# Error code 0x80070643 when installing IIS7 role services

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7, asp.net, windows

I am attempting to install IIS7 "<strike>Application Development</strike>*ASP*" role via the Server Manager's 
"Add Role Services" wizard.  <strike>Some of the roles include ASP.Net, .Net Extensibility, ASP, ISAPI Extensions, etc.</strike> *I have now successfully installed other roles under the Application Development heading.  ASP is the only issue*  When attempting to install these I receive the following error for each service that I attempt to install:

```
Attempt to install <the service name> failed with error code 0x80070643.  Fatal error during installation.
```

I am able to successfully add Role Services that do not belong "Application Development".  For example, I was able to install Health and Diagnostics -> Tracing, Custom Logging, and ODBC Logging without an issue.

I have tried the following:

```
-The 2 Methods here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976982  
    -Microsoft Fix It 50123 *EDIT Added this*
    -Repair .Net Framework 4.0
-Removed WAS (Windows Process Activation Service) from Features, Restarted server, and then attempted to install the role services.
```

I the following System:

Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard SP1 64 bit

**Edit** 3/7/13

I have now successfully been able to add roles under "Application Development", but was not able to do these all at once because I still experience the issue with the "ASP" role.  The issue with this single role was stopping me from installing any of the others at the same time.  I have now individually installed those, but still want to install ASP.

Comment: Have you tried the 1st resolution method in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976982 ?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention.  I tried that before repairing the .Net Framework

Comment: I edited my question to make note of that.

Answer (score 1):

I would try:

- C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ua
- restart.
- add roles/features.
- restart.
- aspnet_regiis.exe -i

If you need other/multiple versions of ASP.NET, you would need to run the appropriate aspnet_regiis.exe -i for that version/platform (x86/x64).

For more details see  see the MSDN page for the [ASP.NET IIS Registration Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  After performing the uninstall I am still getting the error when I attempt to add the roles.  I noticed that it only uninstalls ASP.NET (2.0.50727).  Is that right?

Comment: I now am able to install some of the roles, but still can't install "ASP".  Please see edit in my QUestion.

Answer (score 0):

Since I was unable to get this work any other way, everything was re-installed from scratch and it now functions properly.

Thanks for the answers.